# Mulitple dates formats on two datepicker controls in the same Angular componet

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, angular-moment

I am trying to get two datepickers to display date formats that are different on the same view.  One should display `month/year`, and the other `month/day/year`.  Problem is that the provider injects one format only, so both controls use the same `date format`.  This causes `date.getFullYear()` is not a function error since the month/year datepicker lacks the day.  Below is the provider section in my component-

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: DateAdapter,
    useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
    deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
  },
  { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: RANGE_FORMATS }
],
```

And the RANGE_FORMATS variable:

```
export const RANGE_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM DD YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM DD YYYY',
    },
};
```

The page currently displays '`MM/DD/YYYY`' since the `RANGE_FORMATS` variable "`dateInput`" specifies this.  Both controls then display the `month/day/year`.  What I need is either a way to format the dates displayed in the `html`, or use different providers `dateInput` for each `datepicker` control.

Below is the date range date picker which is in `month/day/year` format-

```
 <div class="toolbar">

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>

  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

</mat-form-field>
<mat-date-range-picker #pickerRange></mat-date-range-picker>
```

Below is the `month/year` datepicker which uses `MM/YYYY` format-

```
 <div>
 <mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-title>Generate Invoice for</mat-card-title>      
    <mat-form-field color="accent">
        <mat-label>Month and Year</mat-label>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #dp
                      startView="multi-year"
                      (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
                      (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)">
      </mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
  <app-datepicker [change]="changedateInput()"></app-datepicker>
  </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>  
 </div>
```

How can I have the date range display `MM/DD/YYYY` and the month year datepicker display `MM/YYYY`?

Answer (score 0):

For change calendar view add startView with option - month, year or multi-year <mat-datepicker #picker1 startView="year"> more info You make find here https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: It is not the calendar view I am looking to change.  It is the input format of the dates.

Comment: Learn this document with atention https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#watching-the-views-for-changes-on-selected-years-and-months.